# flushdb not clear all keys in redis?

Tags: redis

It seems there are still some keys left after i ran redis SHELL command `flushdb`, 
[image]

what are these keys used for and why `flushdb` does not work?

Answer (score 7):

When Redis runs `flushdb` command, it blocks any new writings to the database, and flushes all keys in the database. However, when Redis finishes the `flushdb` command, it can receive new writings, i.e. other Redis client can put new keys into the database.

In your case, I think there're other clients constantly writing to the database. So after you flush the database, new keys are put into Redis by other clients.

If you want to stop any further writing, you have to shutdown Redis server.

Comment: your suggest seems reasonable. I used the server localhost which was installed just 1 hour ago, i didn't tell others. so i think maybe some other backgroud service wrote the redis..

Comment: This is a great answer, just check that another client isnt writing to the same database. helped me!

Comment: In my case, I have the same behavior, but there are no other clients writing. Few keys are not removed, while others are.

Comment: @TheDataScientician I have the same problem as you mention.  Did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: @DaveBlack You can use `client list` to check if there're other clients.

Comment: @for_stack my case is like thedatascientician.  I know there are no other clients.