# Issues to fully delete a hash key in redis

Tags: python, django, redis

i'm using Redis with Python and Django and i have some trouble with the delete of Redis.

I create hash key to store multiple informations about a vehicule, but the user is finished with it, i'm deleting the key with :

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host=settings.REDIS_AD, port=settings.REDIS_PORT, db='14')
key = 'TEST_GMA'
r.delete(key)
```

Most of the time the hash gets deleted, but sometimes it only erase part of the hash and i don't understand why since it seem to be very random.

Comment: Other client might add the hash back after you delete the key. This is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406073/flushdb-not-clear-all-keys-in-redis/42407496).

Comment: I see how that would be possible, but that would mean that the key would only contain data writen by the second client and it's not the case here it really looks like it just didn't delete everything.

Answer (score 1):

use the "hdel" command to delete the redis hash which has multiple key fields.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).