# Sometimes redis keys are not deleted

Tags: redis

I have implemented storing the results of a selection from a database (list) in Redis to speed up data loading on the site. When a cms user performs any operations (creates, deletes or edits article), the keys in redis are dropped and load fresh data from the database.

But sometimes it happens that one or two users do not drop their keys after performing operations with articles and old data remains in redis. The Internet was available, nothing was turned off. Why does this happen - are there any typical reasons that I need to know?

Do I need to block the database so that there are no multiple connections? But redis seems to be single-threaded. What am I doing wrong? The function for key drop is very simple:

```
function articlesRedisDrop($prefix)
{
    $keys = $redis->keys($prefix."*");
    
    if(count($keys) > 0)
    {
        foreach($keys as $key)
        {
            $redis->del($key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406073/flushdb-not-clear-all-keys-in-redis) is a similar question and answer. Also you'd better use `SCAN` instead of `KEYS` command.

Answer (score 0):

guess that an atomic question. After `$redis->keys($prefix."*")`, before `$redis->del($key)`, another connection added refresh data to redis.

You can try to combine get and del operations to single lua script.

```
local keys = redis.call("keys",string.format("%s.*",KEYS[1]))
for _, key in pairs(keys) do
  redis.call("del", key)
end
```

then run the script with `eval` command and `prefix` param. If you meet performance problem with `keys` command, you can try `scan` or store all `prefix` keys to a set then get and delete all.

Comment: I have never worked with lua scripts, I need to try it. How stupid would the decision to simulate a key lock be? For example, I create the key blocked = false. The first user performs the operation and sets the key value to True. It performs its own operation and at the end of its execution sets the value again to false. The second user starts his operation by reading the value of this key in a loop and waiting until the blocked key becomes false?

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue where I'd occasionally have keys that weren't being deleted.  Our Redis implementation was not in Cluster-mode but had a single read/write Primary and two read-only Replicas. If you don't tell Redis to use the Primary for all "write" operations (Set, Remove, Delete, etc.) it may occasionally send some write requests to the Replica(s). Your implementation is not .NET (like mine) but we use a `CommandFlags.DemandMaster` param passed to the "write" operation calls.  Maybe there is something similar in your framework...